# ios 7 video saving issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, ios7

Im saving the video to photolibrary.Its works for previous ios ,In ios 7
videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum this line allways false

here is my code any one can help me.

```
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewmergeVideo.mov"];

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPathDocs];
if (fileExists) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: myPathDocs error:NULL];

}

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=url;
//[exporter setVideoComposition:MainCompositionInst];
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
 {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self _exportDidFinish:exporter];

     });
 }];
```

here is save code

```
- (void)_exportDidFinish:(AVAssetExportSession*)session
{ 
    NSURL *outputURL = session.outputURL;
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"%@",outputURL);

    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL]) {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                            if (error) {
                                                NSLog(@"writeVideoToAssestsLibrary failed: %@", error);

                                            }else{
                                                NSLog(@"Writing3");

                                            }

                                        });

                                    }];
    }
    [library release];
}
```

in previous ios nsurl
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/99B72CBA-A426-4F04-B7B2-2B61F0B0C513/Documents/NewmergeVideo.mov

in ios 7 nsurl
file:///var/mobile/Applications/791244EE-771B-46C9-BD57-BA0BE6CACD3C/Documents/NewmergeVideo.mov

Comment: Having same issue.  Still trying to solve it

Comment: Found the bug.Its not a file path error.check your final video setting.In my code i accidantly put timeScale = 600,I change it to 30 now its work nicely.

Comment: What object are you setting or method calling to set timeScale.  I am using this:
CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);

Comment: MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,TIME_SCALE);

Comment: Thanks a lot , you have just saved me!!!!!!!

Comment: nice to here its works for others

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this code to save file.(It's work correctly)

```
 if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL))
{
      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

-(void) video: (NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo
{
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error);
}
```